# How to combine many worksheet into one worksheet by row

Tags: excel, row, worksheet

I have an Excel workbook that has several worksheet (by number) .
Each worksheet has only values . There are not header. This is
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6NhDb.png)

I need a one worksheet that consolidates all values from each worksheet by row . This is
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aBDhX.png)
How can I do.

Comment: Do can I convert each worksheet to csv then use concat(pandas)  for combine them?

Comment: Hi Rob, 
there are plenty of ways to do it, excel macros, python, power query and etc and etc...
you should at least choose the direction you want to move towards.
The easiest way would be Power Query (with almost no coding) or Excel Macros with coding